# Apex 5 and PL/SQL error in select statements

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex-5

I have this PL/SQL code which does a select from a Table and inserts into a temp Table when an exact match is found, but in a separate view should show all matches if found. So let's say I have a part number called SKU001 and type it in the field, it should do the display in one field and insert into another table. When I only type SKU it should not insert into the other table, but only display all matches like SKU001, SKU002, SKU003 etc. The code works sort off, but I keep getting erros which does not make sense as I am catering for the errors.

So let me try and break it down a bit.
let's say I have a table called TABLENAME with the following:

```
NAME  | STOCKCODE | PRICE | other columns ...
Item1 | SKU001    | 12.99
Item2 | SKU002    | 13.99
Item3 | SKU003    | 14.99
```

The temp table has only the NAME, STOCKCODE and PRICE columns.

To get the data, I have 2 tabular forms which runs the following.

```
select * from TABLENAME where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');
```

and for the TEMPTABLE the Apex page SQL is.

```
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE TEMPTABLE where SESSION_USER=:P4_USER


DECLARE
l_stock VARCHAR2(200);
l_name VARCHAR2(200);
l_price VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into l_stock, l_name, l_price
from TABLENAME where (NAME=:P4_SEARCH) or (BARCODE=:P4_SEARCH) or (STOCKCODE=:P4_SEARCH);
insert into TEMPTABLE (STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE) 
 values (l_stock, l_name, l_price);
     exception
when too_many_rows then
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into l_stock, l_name, l_price
from TABLENAME where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');
when no_data_found then
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into l_stock, l_name, l_price
from TABLENAME where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');
END;
```

When I only this:

```
BEGIN
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into l_stock, l_name, l_price
from TABLENAME where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');
END;
```

it works perfectly each time.

If I execute only this:

```
BEGIN
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into l_stock, l_name, l_price
from TABLENAME where (NAME=:P4_SEARCH) or (BARCODE=:P4_SEARCH) or (STOCKCODE=:P4_SEARCH);
insert into TEMPTABLE (STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE)
END;
```

but when running the entire PL/SQL script like above I get errors as such:
  When I search SKU001, it will display the Search item and add it to the TEMPTABLE, but when I search SKU it will give me an error:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows 
ORA-06512: at line 23 
ORA-01403: no data found
```

NOTE!! Line 23 display here is not Line 23 in the above code due to formatting of my browser, Line 23 is as below:

```
22 ->     when no_data_found then
23 -> select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE into stock, name, price from TABLENAME where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');
```

At the same time, if I clear or reset the session, it displays:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 23
ORA-01403: no data found
```

Which I find strange because I am adding the `exception` for `no_data_found` as well as for `too_many_lines`

What am I doing wrong here? I hope I have provided enough information here in order for it to make sense.

Last Note! The Barcode is part of the search and does not get inserted, just incase someone asks about it. The search is based on Name, Barcode or Stockcode, but Name, Price and Stockcode are displayed based on the search.
P4_USER is a session user I built seperately that just does a select to display the user's inserts only, and not other user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query will not raise a `too_many_rows` exception unless you have duplicate `barcode` `stockcode` or `name`

just raise exeption for `no_data_found` because the first query wants exact match, will raise no data found and then run second query.

```
DECLARE
L_STOCK VARCHAR2(200);
L_BARCODE VARCHAR2(200);
L_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
L_PRICE VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into l_stock, l_name, l_price
from TABLENAME 
where (:P4_SEARCH=NAME) or (:P4_SEARCH=BARCODE) or (:P4_SEARCH=STOCKCODE);
insert 
into TEMPTABLE (STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE)
values (l_stock, l_name, l_price);
exception
when no_data_found 
then
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into stock, name, price
from TABLENAME 
where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');
end;
```

This should then give you ether a match of SKU001 in the first query and insert into TEMPTABLE or if partial match only display results of last query.

Comment: makes sense, but think I did try this, let me verify.

Comment: What the hell. This works, no errors and works both ways!! Thanks!!

Comment: ;) anytime, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try `INSERT..SELECT`

```
insert into TEMPTABLE (STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE)
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
from TABLENAME
where (NAME=:P4_SEARCH) or (BARCODE=:P4_SEARCH) or (STOCKCODE=:P4_SEARCH);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. That also still works with some inserts, but still give the exact same errors and seems to be unhappy with Line 23 as mentioned in my question. So if I run your query alone, it works just like mine did, but not in the complete PL/SQL script.

Answer (score 0):

The "no_data_found" can be caused by Oracle self.
It can not find a proper message to show you.

But have you put the "no_data_found" exception in the exception handler?

```
declare
  ...
begin
  ...
exception
  when no_data_found
  then
    select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE 
    into stock, name, price 
    from TABLENAME 
    where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') 
    or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') 
    or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');

  when others
  then
     ...
end;
```

Comment: I thought that when no data found I just give it an alternate query to run instead of displaying a message. am I wrong?

Comment: With the exception handler you can do almost anything you want.
For example execute a query, start another procedure, show a message.
I haved edited my answer.

Comment: I have both those exeptions in my code `no_data_found` and `too_many_lines`

Comment: If you execute the next query, how many rows are there as result?
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
from TABLENAME 
where (NAME=:P4_SEARCH) 
or (BARCODE=:P4_SEARCH) 
or (STOCKCODE=:P4_SEARCH);

You know the value of :p4_search?

Comment: The idea is that I can do either a regex query and use parts of a collumn to display the results (all results matching) but when an exact match is found insert into TEMPTABLE. P4_SEARCH is a searchfield in Apex where I can search for either BARCODE, NAME, STOCKCODE. so P4_SEARCH is a Text field. I can search sku and will get results back for SKU001, SKU002, SKU003 but if searching for SKU001 as a complete word, it should then find a unique match and insert into TEMPTABLE

Comment: ok, now the tides have turned. I made minor changes and now no longer getting errors, but now the insert does not work without error, the search does work. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you catch two exceptions.

When you search `SKU` you catch the exception `no_data_found` when you execute query:

```
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into l_stock, l_name, l_price
from TABLENAME where (NAME=:P4_SEARCH) or (BARCODE=:P4_SEARCH) or (STOCKCODE=:P4_SEARCH)
```

Then you execute new query from `when no_data_found` section:

```
select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
into l_stock, l_name, l_price
from TABLENAME where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');
```

but this query raise **new** exception `too_many_rows`. Yeah, this query can retuns multiple rows  with  `regexp_like(STOCKCODE, 'SKU', 'i')` condition. But when you use `into` clause you have to be confident that only one record will be returned by your query.  To avoid `too_many_rows` exception you can try to change your query in exception section, as @sagi has advised:

```
when no_data_found then
    insert into TEMPTABLE (STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE)
    select STOCKCODE, NAME, PRICE
    from TABLENAME where regexp_like(NAME, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(BARCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i') or regexp_like(STOCKCODE, :P4_SEARCH, 'i');
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. You are correct with saying that a new query is executed when `no_data_found` but when we get to the execption, it does not raise a new exception due to the regex query to match parts of the column values, there is also no insert statement like in the first query. The last query is not possible, I cannot insert anything into TEMPTABLE if `no_data_found` it can only insert when exact match is found as per the first select.